# Resize form in MS Access by changing Detail.Height

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want the user to be able to change the height of the form while in Form View by clicking a button:

```vb
Private Sub btnChangeHeight_Click()

    booTall = Not booTall

    If booTall Then
        lngHeight = 12400   ' (twips)
    Else
        lngHeight = 1200
    End If

    Me.Detail.Height = lngHeight
    Me.Repaint

    Debug.Print Me.Detail.Height

End Sub
```

The height changes -- `Debug.Print` says so, and a vertical scroll bar appears when `booTall` is `True`.  **But the form won't change its vertical dimension onscreen.**

I also tried this, without success (making sure my button was on the Form header):

```
    Me.Detail.Visible = booTall
```

The solution would seem to depend on properties for the Form and Form Detail section: *Resizable*, *Auto Height*, perhaps *Can Grow*, etc.  But I've fiddled with those and nothing works.

I understand overlapping controls and other things can prevent height adjustments, so I've reduced the form to a minimal layout.  I'm using Access version 2007/2010.

**Some additional info:**  What I actually am working toward is two subforms, (A) above and (B) below, which can independently be collapsed out of view or expanded.  This is for a decision-making form with a LOT of data on it.  I thought if I collapsed the height of (A) or (B), the `CanShrink` property of `Detail` would cause the overall form dimension to change.  In fact, I think I did this a few years ago using Access 2003.  As for using Maximize ... we're setting up this form as re-usable, multiple instances can open.

Comment: I don't know if what you're trying to do is possible or not. I normally set size information on the form's resize event. Is there a reason you need to control the height of your detail section this way? Why not just allow Maximize button or Auto Fill of screen? If i have it correctly, normally when you maximize, the form header and form footer stay the same size while the detail section enlarges.

Comment: Thanks HK1.  Added a paragraph at the end for more about the goal.

Comment: I wouldn't try to do this using the Detail height settings. Better to control the height of your subform controls.

Comment: That was my first approach.  Since I had equal lack of success, I didn't present it.

Comment: Even though I try not to fall into the trap, my attempts were based on the appealing idea that "web pages do it, so why can't Access?"  I realized this and gave up, so the solution from HansUp is extra delightful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*" ... change the height of the form while in Form View by clicking a button"*

Use the form's `.Move` method to change the form's size.  This sample toggles my form's height between 4044 and 8000 twips.

```vb
Private Sub btnChangeHeight_Click()
    Dim lngHeight As Long

    If Me.WindowHeight = 4044 Then
        lngHeight = 8000
    Else
        lngHeight = 4044
    End If
    Me.Move Me.WindowLeft, Height:=lngHeight
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Smandoli.  My impression is you have a larger goal and this was one piece.  But I got lost in the second half of your question.  My gut tells me moving that part to a new question could give us all another interesting and useful Smandoli question.  Cheers.

Comment: I think that question would be "Can I use Can-Grow to make my forms dance up and down?"  The answer is No.  Your advice means I can get (half-way) where I want to go (with a bit more effort) -- and that works for me.  As for the way I dumbed-down my question ... yeh, that often isn't productive.  :-)  Thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: I think I was on a similar road not long ago.  I gave up on can-grow, but wasn't certain whether it absolutely couldn't help or I just couldn't see the answer through my frustration.  So I was extra curious about what you might come up with.  :-)

Comment: Let's go for the Canonical Badge!  (Hmm, I don't see it in the list ... was sure was it there, and you would have one or two.)

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem and found that even if I hid the fields (controls) I didn't want to see the Detail height would not shrink enough. I found if I moved the controls I wanted to hide (so set both .Visible and .Top properties) then Detail.Height would reduce to what I wanted. It's as though even hidden Access refused to ignore the hidden controls

Comment: Thank you.  This adds some insight, and appears to agree in principle with the answer from HansUp.