# How to expand a field on a form only when needed

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to decide the best way to design a form which on occasion has field values which have many characters forcing the to run off of the form.  What would be optimal would be if the field height could expand (together with all the other fields in the following columns) to accommodate the lengthy text.  Is there a way to write code to make this happen but not expand the fields of the records which are not lengthy?

Comment: There's no simple way to do this on a Form (reports do it automatically), since the size of the box would depend on the Font, FontSize, etc etc. I generally just make sure the box is big enough, or include code to open the Access "Zoom" box in instances where I think the user might enter a lot of text.

Comment: thanks. I figured that.

Comment: Let me go searching. Someone had a similar issue (wanted fields to shrink or expand to fill entire window when user resizes).

Comment: The code I worked on was to expand/shrink the WIDTH of fields so they always filled the window (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077559/how-to-resize-side-by-side-controls-in-ms-access-2007) I believe you could modify that to also expand the height of fields.  However, without knowing more details about your environment, I caution that it may be very distracting to a user if your field placement moves around based on # of characters as they scroll thru records.

Comment: Wayne thanks. The environment is just one screen where the user will probably have no more than 4-6 records. The only thing is that the key field to look at is a description type field in memo format and cant be quite long sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a control holing 'notes' data and experienced the same problem. I ended up creating a report to hold the notes and dropping it on the main form as a sub. Link the two forms as you would with any subform.

Then set the 'can grow' property to 'yes' and bobs your uncle. Worked really well.

Answer (score 2):

**1:**  The Access "zoom box" (mentioned by Wayne G. Dunn) is what many people would use for this.  You can instruct users, possibly, to press `F2` when the focus is on that field -- up comes the zoom box.

**2:**  You can make a more elegant solution that basically does the same thing: make your own modal form which serves as an input box.

**3: ... Okay ...** you can make a field expand vertically and move all the other fields below to accommodate.  Unfortunately you have to code all that.  More below.

You may have to use a button to let the user toggle the expanded view.  (You could possibly make the form respond automatically to a long entry, but that's a lot of code!)  You'll have a variable `booExpanded` that is normally set False.  When True, you will reset the field positions with the `.top` property.  It helps to start with a constant `EXP-HEIGHT` which is the additional vertical amount in [twips](http://www.applecore99.com/api/api012.asp).

A bit more information about toggling the *form* height is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22046314/122139).

You could get creative with form containers such as `Page`, or put your one expandable field in the `Detail` section, but I seem to recall deciding one time that none of that worked so well.